# WildFly primefaces Fileupload customization (Encrypted tempFile)

Tags: servlets, file-upload, primefaces, wildfly, temporary-files

In WildFly26 (undertow) during HttpServletRequest parsing, the parser streams uploded file to the server as temp File.

The undertow's

*io.undertow.server.handlers.form.MultiPartParserDefinition.MultiPartUploadHandler*
class do this.

Primefaces supports also commons-fileupload too.

I  would like encrypt the so creating temp files. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Comment: I edited the question. There is just the main goal. thanks.

Comment: Nope, there aren't multiple questions in one. That it causes *you* to have multiple questions in your head because you don't understand any thing isn't a valid reason to closevote this question as "there are multiple questions" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doesn't find any solution, so I change primefaces fileuplod method to commons file-upload, based on the primefaces documentation:
[Primefaces 13 documentation](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/13_0_0/#/components/fileupload)

Yes commons-fileupload make plain temporary files too, but it is more easier to change.

I made a pull-request (perhaps without chance) which based on 1.5 version.

[Pull request to commons-fileupload](https://github.com/apache/commons-fileupload/pull/285)

With this version you can add an CipherServiceProvider by java SPI, and then the temporary files will be encrypted.